# How to transfer a virtual machine to another computer via usb?

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm helping out in computer science for our school Open Day and to show off the computing department, I'm planning on presenting a game I wrote recently.

I wrote this game in Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon in VirtualBox and the school computers are running Windows 7 but they also have VirtualBox. So my plan is to copy the virtual machine folder for Linux Mint and transfer it to the school computer via a USB flash drive.

Of course it's a huge file (20.3 GB, it has a VDI extension), so I compressed it and it is now 10.17 GB in size. I have a USB drive that should be able to hold it and it's FAT32, so it works on my Mac and the school computers.

My question is, will this work? Will I be able to just copy the vdi onto the USB, plug it into the school computer, extract the zip file and run Linux Mint in VirtualBox? And if this will not work, what do I need to do? I'm not an expert in virtual machines, so I only know the basics, like how to create one, and some simple settings you can change for optimisation.

P.S. I've found out that FAT32 cannot hold files larger than 2GB, but exFAT can, so would it work if I changed the USB format to exFAT?

Comment: You should zip the whole vm folder, not just the VDI. Then you can just open .vbox file.

Comment: I did, I zipped the whole folder. Sorry, I wrote it wrong in the question.

Comment: It should be fine then, if the host machine has enough ram & cores for your VM configuration. You can always change the configuration before running the VM.

Comment: So when I put it onto the USB and I plug it into the school computer, will I just have to extract it on the USB, and double-click the .vbox file? I would have thought you need the VirtualBox program on the USB.

Comment: You said the machines have virtual box installed already?

Comment: The school computers do, but I'm going to run the VM from the USB, because our accounts only have 1GB of storage. Everything else is on the servers, I would assume.

Comment: I found out today that we are going to be using different computers and they do not have VirtualBox installed, so if I want to run the VM from the USB, will I need to install Portable VirtualBox on the USB?

Comment: Install and test the portable Virtualbox on your USB at home first.  I've never used it so I couldn't really comment. Depending on what the game is written in you may be able to run it directly on the other PC's.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Right now the VM is now extracted on the USB, but it won't open because of some errors, such as another virtual machine existing with the same UUID. But I think I can get it to work. My computer is a Mac, so I will have to plug the USB into a PC before I install Portable VirtualBox on it.

Comment: The game is written in C, using SDL, so I wouldn't be able to run it on other PCs. The one's at school do not have a C compiler and I would have to install all the right SDL frameworks. So I'm just going to have to stick to the VM.